# Using grpc+mpi protocol in distributed tensorflow - Error

Tags: tensorflow, mpi, distributed, openmpi

I have just compiled TensorFlow (master) with MPI support and am now specifying the "grpc+mpi" protocol in the tf.train.Server object. However, when attempting to launch the training procedure, there is always exactly one worker who fails with the error

`F ./tensorflow/contrib/mpi/mpi_utils.h:47] Failed to convert worker name to MPI index: ps:0:0`

Every time I reproduce the error, it is a different worker that fails to "convert". It is quite suspicious to me that the name that it fails to convert is a "worker" name considering that it actually cannot "convert" a property of the Parameter Server.

The whole training procedure works fine when using the "standard" protocol "grpc".

Each worker as well as the single parameter server run on a dedicated machine (no shared machine).
The OpenMPI version is 2.1.1

How would I approach debugging this? Unfortunately I don't have much knowledge of MPI.

Thanks,

Mat

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem when I used TensorFlow with MPI support. The reason is that I didn't use the mpirun to launch the training procedure.

For example, my train script is `mpi_train.sh`:

```
#! /bin/bash

host=$(hostname -s)
if [[ $host = "node-1" ]]; then
        job_name=ps
        task_id=0
elif [[ $host = "node-2" ]]; then
        job_name=worker
        task_id=0
elif [[ $host = "node-3" ]]; then
       job_name=worker
       task_id=1
fi

cd /test/models/inception

bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_distributed_train --batch_size=32 --data_dir=/test/data/ILSVRC2012 --job_name=${job_name} --task_id=${task_id} --ps_hosts=10.0.20.14:2276 --worker_hosts=10.0.20.15:2276,10.0.20.16:2276 --protocol=grpc+mpi --max_steps=1020
```

I should use the mpirun to launch my train script:

`mpirun -host 10.0.0.14,10.0.0.15,10.0.0.16 /test/mpi_train.sh`